# If given the Vasicek Interest rate model $dR(t)=(\alpha-\beta R(t))dt +\sigma dW(t)$ how do I use Ito's lemma to find $d(e^{\beta t}R(t))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

If given the Vasicek Interest rate model $dR(t)=(\alpha-\beta R(t))dt +\sigma dW(t)$ how do I use Ito's lemma to find $d(e^{\beta*t}R(t))$ and simplify so it is a solution that does not include R(t).

To further this question, how would I go about integrating the step above to solve for R(t) then use this to find the expectation and variance of R(t) along with it's limiting behaviors

Could someone please walk me through the steps of doing this! It would be very much appreciated

EDIT: I think I figured out how to do the first part:

let $f(R(t))=e^{\beta t}R(t)$

$f'(R(t))=e^{\beta t}$

$f''(R(t))=0$

$f'(t)=\beta e^{\beta t}R(t)$

then, $d(e^{\beta t} R(t)) = \beta e^{\beta t} R(t)dt + e^{\beta t} dR(t) + 0$

$=e^{\beta t} dR(t) + \beta e^{\beta t} R(t)dt$

Now i sub dR(t) into the above equation and simplify to get

$d(e^{\beta t} R(t)) = e^{\beta t}((\alpha - \beta R(t))dt + \sigma dW(t)) + \beta e^{\beta t} R(t)dt = \alpha e^{\beta t}dt + \sigma e^{\beta t}dW(t)$

Is the above correct notation so far?

Comment: I think that you should write like this $f(t, R(t)) = e^{\beta t}R(t)$, everything else seems to be correct.

Comment: would you mind helping with finding the distribution of R(t) then also the mean and variance then finding the limiting behaviour of E(R(t)) as t goes to infinity? @Hello

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y_t = e^{\beta t}R_t$, hence
$$dY_t = \alpha e^{\beta t} dt + \sigma e^{\beta t} dW_t,$$
$$Y_t = Y_0 +  \alpha\int\limits_0^t e^{\beta s} ds + \sigma \int\limits_0^te^{\beta s} dW_s,$$
$$e^{\beta t}R_t = R_0 +  \alpha\int\limits_0^t e^{\beta s} ds + \sigma \int\limits_0^te^{\beta s} dW_s,$$
$$e^{\beta t}R_t = R_0 +  \frac{\alpha}{\beta} e^{\beta t} + \sigma \int\limits_0^te^{\beta s} dW_s,$$
$$R_t = e^{-\beta t}R_0 +  \frac{\alpha}{\beta} + \sigma \int\limits_0^te^{\beta (s-t)} dW_s.$$
This is the final expression for $R_t$. 
$$\mathbb{E}R_t = e^{-\beta t}\mathbb{E}[R_0] +  \frac{\alpha}{\beta},$$
therefore $\mathbb{E}R_t \rightarrow \frac{\alpha}{\beta}.$

Comment: how do i know what the expected value of R(0) is?@Hello

Comment: Because it's usually given. But in general you don't know, that is why I wrote $\mathbb{E}R_0$ and not an exact number.

Comment: Ohhh okay I understand! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, good luck!

Comment: what happens if i let $R(0) = \alpha / \beta?$ Is this the mean reverting property? @Hello

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this property and I don't have any background in finance. Probably if you specify this property I could help.

Comment: I believe there's a $-1/(\beta e^{\beta t})$ missing in the solution $R_t$.

Answer (score 0):

Vasicek Interest rate model has the desirable property that the interest rate is mean-reverting. When $R(t) = \frac{\alpha}{\beta} $ the drift term in $dR(t)$ is zero. When $R(t) > \frac{\alpha}{\beta} $ this term is negative, Which pushes $R(t)$ back toward $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} $. Likewise when $R(t) < \frac{\alpha}{\beta} $ this term is positive, which again pushes $R(t)$ back toward $\frac{\alpha}{\beta} $